# Assertion failed in Codeblocks,glade,gtk

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am having troubles upon runtime in codeblocks. It says “(HelloWorld.exe:3312): libglade-CRITICAL **: glade_xml_relative_file: assertion
`filename != NULL’ failed”

I am using Glade, and GTK at the same time to build a UI for my project, but I've been working on it for days and I still couldn't figure out what's wrong?
Thank you.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

     /*import glade file*/
     xml = glade_xml_new("hello.glade", NULL, NULL);

     /* get a widget (useful if you want to change something) */
     widget = glade_xml_get_widget(xml, "mainWindow");

     /* connect signal handlers */
     glade_xml_signal_autoconnect(xml);

     /*show widget*/
     gtk_widget_show (widget);

     gtk_main();

     return 0;
}
```

It builds fine, it just won't run when I try to run it.

Comment: You sure the file exists?

Comment: From the error, the reason may be that you are not pasing the file name in proper format. After parsing for filename the `filename` becomes `NULL`, that is why assertion fails.

Comment: @v3ga yes, it is on the same folder as my project

Comment: @MadHatter it is really hello.glade , it is on the same folder as my project, as I mentioned above

Comment: Try mentioning complete path, right from `/` if in linux or from `X:` if on windows

Comment: @MadHatter still not working unfortunately

Comment: Is the directory you execute your binary in directory that also contains `hello.galde`?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two formats of a glade file: `1:libglade` , `2:gtkBuilder`.

I have also faced the same problem when i was working on my summer project. instead of building your glade file using `glade_xml_new()` use `gtk_builder_new()` because i think your glade file  if of `gtkBuilder` type.

**sample program:**

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder; 
    GtkWidget  *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new(); 

    gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "name of your glade file", NULL);/*this api is used to                                                  
                               build the glade file which is created by using glade(glade3) UI designer.*/


    window = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( gtkBuilder, "name of your window") );


    gtk_builder_connect_signals( gtkBuilder, NULL ); /*connecting signals so that appropriate   
                                       handler can be called to handle the button clicked event*/
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main(); /*it is basically a loop to make window appear. if we not write it then window                    
                 will appear but disappear after few seconds automatically.*/
    return 0;
}
```

the sample program is not complete it is only to understand the right way to build glade file for
complete program and for more info on how to program in c using gtk libraries to build GUI's you can refer http://programming-simplified.blogspot.com